# swift - Twitter login button created with no completion block?

Tags: ios, swift, twitter, xcode7-beta4

Im implementing a TWTRLoginButton but for some reason the completion block isnt registering/getting called, I have no idea why this is....

**Login button initialization:**

```
self.twitterLoginView = TWTRLogInButton(logInCompletion: { session, error in
        if (session != nil) {
            print("signed in as \(session.userName)");
        } else {
            print("error: \(error.localizedDescription)");
        }
    })
```

**Error, when clicking buton:**

> TWTRLogInButton was created with no completionBlock set

Answer (score 0):

You need to let the TwitterKit to handle reopening the app when it's redirected back from twitter:

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    let twtrHandled = TWTRTwitter.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, options: options)
    return twtrHandled
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Take one UIButton either in Code or in Story board then give the button action to the following method.

```
 -(IBAction)twitterLogin:(id)sender
{

    [[Twitter sharedInstance] logInWithCompletion:^(TWTRSession *session, NSError *error){
        if (session)
        {
             [[Twitter sharedInstance]ini]
             [[[Twitter sharedInstance] APIClient] loadUserWithID:[session userID]
                                                       completion:^(TWTRUser *user,
                                                                    NSError *error)
              {
                  // handle the response or error
                  if (![error isEqual:nil]) {

                      NSLog(@"Twitter info   -> user = %@ ",user.description);
                      {
                          NSMutableDictionary *dict =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
                          [dict setValue:user.userID forKey:@"id"];
                          [dict setValue:user.name forKey:@"name"];
                          [dict setValue:user.screenName forKey:@"screenName"];
                          NSLog(@"User Description is %@",dict);
                      }

                  } else {
                  }
              }];

         } else {
             NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
         }
     }];

}
```